# Icon on card is not showing when setting icon source as icon class column in Apex 21.2

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I am trying to add icon in my Apex 21.2 cards region using SQL query. I used the following sql query:

```
select 1 card_primary_key,   
  'Users' card_title,    
  'Product Users' card_subtitle,    
  'fa-users-alt' card_icon       
from dual
```

Then under attributes, under `Icon and Badge`, I set `Icon Source=Icon class column` and `Icon Column = CARD_ICON`, and `Icon Position= Start`

The title and subtitle are the only things showing, no icon shows up, there is just an empty space to the left of text.

I inspected the page looked at the html generated

```
<span class="a-CardView-icon u-color fa-users-alt" aria-hidden="true" title=""></span>
```

Could it be because area-hidden is set to true? If so, how do I change it? I did try changing `fa-users-alt` to `fa fa-users-alt` etc. but nothing worked

Can't figure out what is happening here. Would really appreciate some help. I am using Template Cards Container and Style A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick try on apex.oracle.com (which has been upgraded to 22.1 already, but that shouldn't make a difference) and it worked just fine. [image: screenshot]

Used query

```
  select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO,
       'fa fa-users-alt' as icon
  from EMP
```

Settings are same as yours and the icon shows up just fine. The html element is same as yours too - with aria-hidden="true":

```
<span class="a-CardView-icon u-color fa fa-users-alt" aria-hidden="true" title=""></span>
```

Comment: Interesting - when I changed the column name to « icon » instead of « card_icon », it worked

Comment: Strange, for me the column alias doesn't seem to matter. "ICON_XX" works too.

Comment: did it work for you with card-icon alias?

Comment: By the way, I added two more cards and something strange is happening - the icon shows up on two of the cards but not on the third one

Comment: Works with card-icon alias, I did have to enclose that in double quotes in my query, card_icon works too. I suggest setting up an example on apex.oracle.com and giving me the credentials - happy to take a look.